# RegEx for creating hashtag text

Tags: objective-c, regex

I'm writing an iPhone where you can create various tags. A tag's format should like like this:

#a-z

where the first character of the tag is always the #, while the charaters after the # are any between A-Z and a-z. Could somebody explain how I would write this RegEx, and if possible how I'd implement it with NSString's?

**Edit:**

Here's how you'd implement this with an NSString and NSPredicate:

```
    NSString *hashtagRegEx = @"#[A-Za-z]+";
    NSPredicate *hashtagTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", hashtagRegEx];

    if ([hashtagTest evaluateWithObject:textField.text] == NO) { // Not Valid Hashtag

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regular expression:

```
#[a-zA-Z]+
```

Comment: is there a way to make this RegEx accept text without the hashtag in front? For example, these would be valid entries: #bunny, bunny. But not this bun#ny or bunny#. The hashtag must either be first or nor present. How would I do that? Thanks again.

Comment: You can use the regex "?" operator, which matches zero or one of something. For example, regex "#?1234" would accept "1234" or "#1234".